# Error Consuming .net Webservice(asmx) from Android Xamarin(VS2015)

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, asmx

i have created a web service in VS2015. My web service is having a function **SignUpUser** it will take 3 parameter and returns result in integer.

```
    MyFirstWebService.Service Serv = new MyFirstWebService.Service();
    int result = Serv.SignUpUser("abc", "password", "abc@gmail.com");
```

am calling the above code from button click event of VS2015(Xamarin Android)
but it is giving me the error as below

```
system.net.webexception error connectfailure (connection refused)
at system.net.sockets.socketexception:connection refused
at system.net.webconnection.connect(system.net.httpwebrequest request)
```

i have checked so many links, everywhere mentioned instead of **localhost** use **10.0.2.2** 
http://localhost:58614/Service.asmx but it is not working. i have tested my webservice with C# windows application its working without any issue. Did i missed anything particularly??

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled?  If you are using IIS Express or the debug server in VS, is is setup to accept external requests?

Comment: @Jason My firewall is enabled still am getting the error I don't have any clue !! And its working if connect with some other application

Comment: Your firewall could be blocking requests - try disabling it.